# Disable all audio on GPUImageMovieWriter

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

I need to disable audio completely on GPUImage recording as it is not needed for my purposes. I am hoping to reduce file size while keeping video quality high.

Any suggestions?

Ommitting this line did not do the trick:

```
//videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;
```

Comment: `videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil`

Answer (score 1):

```
videoCamera.audioEncodingTarget = nil
```